# Code::Blocks: no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, codeblocks

I'm new to Ubuntu and have just installed Code::Blocks on Ubuntu. Then I created a Console Application with default settings. However, when I clicked "Build and run", I got the following build log:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c /path/to/myproject/main.c -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -o bin/Debug/myproject obj/Debug/main.o
g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: no such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

So it seems that file "main.o" was not generated, and it was true. So is there a way that can solve the problem?

Comment: open a console window in main.c directory and type in `gcc -Wall main.c -o exe.exe` what happens?

Comment: Did you change anything in the output directory settings?